# Pandas: Date comparison with column addition based on values in rows

Tags: python, excel, date, pandas

I have a number of excel files that following a similar format:

```
|name| email| cat1| cat2| cat3
 smith email 01JAN2016 01JAN2014 01JAN2015
```

The first two columns contain strings (name and email addrs) while each of the following columns contain dates when each person completed each item in cat(x).

I would like to run a comparison to current_date, adding a new column 'status' which will have a value of 'compliant' or 'delinquent' based on whether any date in a row is prior to current date then output the new dataframe to an excel spreadsheet.

My initial attempts let me filter 'older' dates rather easily, however, when I tried to add a column using a conditional everything started to break:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pd_output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', datetime_format= 'mmm d yyy')

df = pd.read_excel(tracker,'Sheet1')

print(df.values)    # Displays dates as 'Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00') any value which is < current_date displays as 'True' else 'False'

print(df < current_date)  # removes dates that are not older than current_date but does not delete column, ie someone with no old dates will still show up with column 3+ being blank

# a couple version of what I have been trying - unsuccessfully
df['Status'] = np.where(df[df < current_date], 'delinquent', 'compliant'  # error: 'wrong number of items passed

df['Status'] = np.where(df == 'True', 'delinquent', 'compliant'  # error: 'str' obj has no attr 'view'  

df['Status' = df.Set.map(lambda x: 'delinquent' if 'True' in df else 'compliant'  # from another post - error 'no attr 'Set' or 'map'

  # send to output excel
  df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

I would like to have an output which either displays rows with the 'Status' column addition showing where there was an 'offending date' within the row - detonated with 'compliant' or 'delinquent.'  I feel like I am making my comparisons incorrectly (using True instead of another .where) but can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to create a new column based on values of one or more other columns, you usually use one of the `apply` functions.  When the function is of multiple columns, as is the case here, you use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Here is an approximation of what I think you are trying to do:

```
df['Status'] = df.apply (
    lambda df : (
      'delinquent' 
          if any (df[i] < current_date for i in ("cat1","cat2","cat3")) 
       else 'compliant'
    ) ,
    axis = 1
)
```

(FYI I thought from your logic that "delinquent" meant the date was before the current date, if I was wrong please reverse the `<` symbol to `>` in what I have above.)

Let's unpack this a little. The `apply` applies a vectorized function to the entire dataframe.  We need to apply to the entire dataframe because we are looking at more than one column; shortly, we will specify which ones. The function is the `lambda` we've defined.  The `axis = 1` argument tells `apply` to apply the lambda to each row (this is not the default, the default is `axis = 0`, which applies to each column - not what we want). The `lambda` itself looks at all 3 of your date columns by name, returning "delinquent" if any one of them are before the current date. I use the `any()` with the generator expression inside just to avoid the drudgery of writing something like `if df["cat1"] < current_date or df["cat2"] < current_date or df["cat3"] < current_date` and so forth.

Note that all of this depends on your 3 date columns being of type `datetime` - I am assuming that they are.

If you had only one date column, say, "cat1", you could use the slightly simpler [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) on that one column.

```
df['Status'] = df['cat1'].apply (
    lambda x : 'delinquent' if x < current_date else 'compliant' 
)
```

The rationale for doing this is the simpler function and the lack of the `axis` argument.  So generally, people use `Series.apply` when they are applying a function of only one column, and `DataFrame.apply` if the function is of more than one column.

Comment: This worked exactly how I was hoping.  I really appreciate your time and added explanation (for my future edification).  I am glad you were able to interpret what I was asking even though I wasn't able to eloquently convey my question.  Cheers!

Comment: Glad to help!  I'm glad the additional stuff I put in was helpful too - `apply` is definitely a useful tool.  Thanks for accepting.